# VBA : Copy all data to another workbook's sheet

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, excel-2007

I have a macro that works well on my pc, but doesn't in my friend's pc, which I've never seen before.

The error comes from this part :

```
...
Workbooks("GOP_Flow_" + Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "yyyy") + Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mm")).Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Copy
main.Worksheets(2).Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
...
```

There's a run-time error 9 : "subscript out of range" on the copy line.
- How could this kind of thing happen since we use the same version of Excel?
- Is there an alternative way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Subscript out of range means you're trying to either copy from or to an undefined range. Either there's no "main" workbook declared in the script, no worksheet with index 2, it can't find the workbook with that specific date in the name, or not find the sheet with index 1 within that workbook.
For example: ActiveSheet.Range("A0").value = "something" will also generate this error.

Comment: Thank you Rik. Your help is liked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess... You have different options in your folder options settings for viewing file names.

On your PC, the option `Hide extensions for know file types` is checked, so the file's  extension is not visible in the file's name. Hence `Workbooks("GOP_Flow_201704)` works for you without the file extension.

On your friend's PC, the option is not checked, so the extension makes part of workbooks name, something like `"GOP_Flow_201704.xlsx"`, so you will need to add the extension to the name...

```
Workbooks("GOP_Flow_" & _
 Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "yyyy") & _
 Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mm") & ".xlsx")...
'                                        ^^^^^^^
```

As a solution, putting the file's extension in the name **works in both cases**.

p.s. By the way, dont use `+` for string concatenation, use `&` instead.

Comment: Thank you ASH ! That's exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @Francis you are welcome, glad to know that it helped.